# Как пропускать исключения в дебагере Delphi?

Tags: delphi, исключения

Есть код:

```
1.  try  
2.    f := strtofloat('q');  
3.  finally  
4.    f := 0;  
5.  end;
```

Во второй строке выскакивает ошибка:

> EConverError .. with message 'q' is not a valid floating point value.

То есть выходит конструкция try finally как бы не работает. В Delphi 7 захожу в Debugger Options и снимал флажок со Stop on Delphi exceptions, а в Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010 не знаю, что с этим делать. (И так не только с этим типом исключений)
Подскажите, как с этим справиться в обоих средах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает, не бойся. Я когда только Delphi изучал, тоже думал, что исключительные ситуации не срабатывают. Просто дело в том, что когда компилируешь программу и запускаешь её непосредственно из среды Delphi, то она запускается в режиме отладки, поэтому эксепшены не срабатывают, дебаггер выдает все ошибки программисту. А вот когда запустишь скомпилированный exe-Файл, то все работает!

Comment: Это кажеться в environment options - ах настраиваеться....

Comment: Спасибо! Тогда неплохо было бы узнать, где бы всё-таки снять "нужный флажок", чтобы каждый раз не выскакивало окно (в нём можно указать игнор только одного типа ошибок).

Comment: Это уже в дебаггере надо поковыряться...

Answer (score 1):

В диалоговом окне дебаггера, которое отображается, когда возникает это исключение, есть чекбокс `Ignore this exception type`. Воспользуйтесь этим чекбоксом, если вы не желаете видеть исключения такого типа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]